# where clause regexp_like (new line feed, carriage retun, double spaces, �)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to ask you if someone can help me out writing a regular expression to check DB for (new line feed, carriage retun, double spaces, �) in a field.

I achieved the same with some or and instr function but would like to learn a bit on reg expression.

So here is my working where clause to identify such cases:

```
and ((instr (the_value, CHR (10)) > 0) 
  or (instr (the_value, CHR (13)) > 0) 
  or (instr (the_value, '  ') > 0) 
  or (instr(the_value,'�') > 0)
)
```

Thanks a lot for any support you may have,

Comment: If you just want to search for whitespace, use `\s`. I don’t know what character `�` is supposed to be.

Comment: The question was ment to accomplish the same in a regular expression, the square is a weird character which is stored as is  the field.

Answer (score 7):

you can do something like `|\r|\n|�` as the regex. As Oracle doesn't support `\r` and `\n`, we use the `chr()` function to splice them in:

```
where regexp_like(the_value, '  |'||chr(13)||'|'||chr(10)||'|�')
```

or use the corresponding chr(number) in place of the � literal

Comment: Using this trick with regexp_instr worked great too.